# How would I go about creating a login

Tags: android, mysql, authentication

The set-up:
I have an android application that so far can register a user by inserting values into a remote mysql database. I'm now trying to implement the log in.

I was thinking that I can add a "logged in" column to the user table in the database that would store whether or not the user was logged in. Then I would have a trigger that would log the user off after a certain amount of time has been elapsed.

The application's use is to retrieve files based upon if the user has access to a certain file. For this I have an "access" column in the user table table specifying the access a user has to a certain file. I was thinking that when a user clicks an item in a list the application would send their login information and the server would determine if the information was correct then check to see if they had access to the specified file then send back the file if the information is correct.

The problem I'm having though is that checking the registration information takes about 2 seconds alone(due to connecting to the socket and sending a string over the network) and if I try to check both the login and the access id it would take slightly longer.

I feel as if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel but I can't find any viable resources on this matter. Criticisms? Suggestions?

(I wouldn't mind doing a complete redesign I just need to know where to start)

Comment: i would suggest **not** having a column which determines if the user is logged in or not(server side). the client app(android) should be sending the server some sort of access token which was acquired via in a successful login and this would determine whether the user was logged in(match client access token to token in server database). every request would require the android app to be sending this token

Comment: @binnyb That makes much more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never connect a client to a db-server. There's no way to intercept hacking attempts, because privileges are very basic (SELECT, UPDATE, etc., they ignore the query):

```
UPDATE users SET name='%s' WHERE userID=%i // where %i will be defined as the real userID
```

Above should be a valid query to update the user's account-information, however, a hacker can easily intercept this and change it into:

```
UPDATE users SET name='%s' WHERE userID=15 // ... or any other variable
```

Instead, you should create a web based API which will validate each query, or better, support only specific API-commands:

```
account/update.json?name=%s
```

Comment: Would this still be true if the client only had privileges to insert and select on that table?

Comment: Sure: `SELECT email FROM users WHERE userID=%i` can still be hacked by replacing the `%i`-param. Besides that, a hacker can decompile your application or use a network-sniffer to find out to what MySQL-server you are connecting, and write his own SELECT and INSERT-queries (eg. `SELECT email FROM users`, without query, so he has a complete copy of all your users' email-addresses.).